# Is there any command to find out the current math font used?

Tags: math-mode, fonts, math-fonts

I found very handy commands to know the current font families used, namely, `\rmdefault`, `\ttdefault`, `\sfdefault`. And, what's more, I can redefine the values in `\ttdefault` and `\sfdefault` to locally change the families in my document, e.g., `\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmvtt}`.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
\noindent the name of my roman font is \texttt{\rmdefault}\\
the name of my tt-font is \texttt{\ttdefault}\\
the name of my sans serif font is \texttt{\sfdefault}
\end{document}
```

Alas, I do not find the equivalent commands for **math fonts**. Are there any commands that provide the current math fonts used (something like `\mathrmdefault`)?

Comment: Math font setup is very different from text. It's not just “choose a font family”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find out all math fonts by `\expandafter\meaning\the\textfont <number>`. Replace `<number>` by `0` and then `1`, `2`, until `nullfont` is returned. Do the same for `scriptfont` and `scriptscriptfont` instead of `textfont`.

Example:

```
0: \expandafter\meaning\the\textfont0

1: \expandafter\meaning\the\textfont1

2: \expandafter\meaning\the\textfont2

3: \expandafter\meaning\the\textfont3

4: \expandafter\meaning\the\textfont4

5: \expandafter\meaning\the\textfont5

6: \expandafter\meaning\the\textfont6

7: \expandafter\meaning\the\textfont7

8: \expandafter\meaning\the\textfont8

\bye
```

[image]